# Custom Map Image WIndows Phone 7

Tags: wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7, dictionary

I have custom map image with specific height and width.
i need to map x-y coordinates of image to latitude longitude from four corner latitude longitude available.

this requirement is for fulfill current location of user into custom image map.

more on this on image i have specific few points on image, based on current position of user, i need to find near by point on image in Windows Phone Application.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [Bing Maps Silverlight Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681884.aspx) for WP7, there are APIs for want you want to achieve.

The [Map](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.map.aspx) class for example provides methods [LocationToViewportPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.locationtoviewportpoint.aspx) and [ViewportPointToLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mapcore.viewportpointtolocation.aspx) for converting coordinates.

There is also the class [MercatorUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mercatorutility.aspx) which provides helpful methods like [LocationToLogicalPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mercatorutility.locationtologicalpoint.aspx) and [LogicalPointToLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.core.mercatorutility.logicalpointtolocation.aspx).

However, depending on what you mean with *custom map image*, nobody except you would possibly know how it maps to view coordinates.

Comment: OK but i need to add functionality to display route between two place so it is possible to add place as well as display roue?

Comment: Of course, just look for classes [Pushpin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.pushpin.aspx), [MapPolyline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.maps.mapcontrol.mappolyline.aspx) and similar.